# GCP Cloud Composer - not able to download large file to data folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, download, airflow, google-cloud-composer, gcsfuse

Every week I have to download a file from ftp server to GCS bucket and then import that file from GCS bucket to BigQuery. I started implementing this dataflow job in GCP Cloud Composer.

I broke dataflow into three tasks

- Download file from ftp server and store it in Cloud Composer data folder. (`/home/airflow/gcs/data`).
- Move the file from Cloud Composer data folder to GCS bucket.
- Import data from GCS bucket to BigQuery.

I am facing issues on downloading file from ftp server to Cloud Composer data folder. Approximate size of file is 20 Gb. I used `wget` command to download the file, the exact command is `wget -c "remote_file_path" -P "/home/airflow/gcs/data"`. Task is starting fine, but its failing after 30 mins and file size in data folder is reflecting as zero bytes. I checked logs and didn't find any errors.

I tried the same procedure with other file of size 1Gb, it worked like charm.

I also tried using `SFTPOperation`, after one hour of running I got error saying `Key-exchange timed out waiting for key negotiation`.

Please help me in figuring this out. I also open to other solutions to implement this dataflow.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that Krisjan answer hits the target. There was some known issue for GCSfuse in versions from Composer >= 1.12.1 (short moments of mounted dirs unavailability - causing Input/Output errors in Airflow; problems with copying of large files, resulting in OOM kills). Updating should fix the issue indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Cloud Composer environment solved the issue for us.

We've encountered similar issues with files larger than approx. 1GB. Tasks are failing after 30 minutes and file size of 0 bytes in the /data folder.

We were using Cloud Composer version 1.12.3. The release notes (https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes of version 1.12.5 mention;

> Improved GCSfuse stability to resolve intermittent issues where the
> mounted directory was unavailable

So we've updated the Cloud Composer instance to version 1.13.0 and it seems to fix the problem.